# Bitnami Mongodb changed member's hostname from services to IP adresses on it's own and now I am unable to change it back

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, mongodb-query, okd

As in the title, mongodb just changed (I think) on it's own member's hosts, excpet arbiter, from for example *mongodb-0.mongodb-headless.infrastructure.svc.cluster.local:27017* to IP adresses on the cluster (OKD), which in turn totally blocked whole thing from being repaired

```
test> rs.config()
{
  _id: 'rs0',
  version: 8,
  term: 24,
  members: [
    {
      _id: 0,
      host: '192.168.120.137:30100',
      arbiterOnly: false,
      buildIndexes: true,
      hidden: false,
      priority: 5,
      tags: {},
      secondaryDelaySecs: Long("0"),
      votes: 1
    },
    {
      _id: 1,
      host: 'mongodb-0.mongodb-headless.infrastructure.svc.cluster.local:27017',
      arbiterOnly: true,
      buildIndexes: true,
      hidden: false,
      priority: 0,
      tags: {},
      secondaryDelaySecs: Long("0"),
      votes: 1
    },
```

There are 3 members of this mongodb cluster, and every one of them got this change, the worst part is that I cannot change it back, As there is no primary I am unable to use rs.reconfig(), I cannot use rs.stepDown(), I am unable to use rs.initiate as every one of this pods thinks it's still part of rs. I am unable to do anything from arbiter as it calls for privilges with error:

```
> MongoServerError: not authorized on admin to execute command {
> replSetGetConfig: 1, $db: "admin" }
```

It looks like Mongodb just choose to break itself, as I did not do any commands nor anyone else.
All I can do is to restart pods, or change their configuration but nothing helps as even If I reset them all this configuration persists.

Did anyone happend to have problem like this?